# Does WF4 support BPEL?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, bpel

I was wondering whether Windows Workflow Foundation 4 supports BPEL at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, WF4 uses XAML instead. See [here](http://xhinker.com/post/WF4WF-and-BPEL.aspx) for a bit more info.